# Loop only executes once/

Tags: javascript, html, while-loop

In the code below 'len' is the length of text in a

tag, the user enters a letter in a textbox, and inside 'result', with the help of .indexof() I am storing the index number of the letter present in the paragraph and then printing that letter in another

tag.
But this loop only runs once whereas I want it to run until the statement in the while loop is true.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Find  letter:</p>
  
  <form id="chk" method="post">
    <label for="scen">Enter a scentence</label>
    <!--<input type="text" name="scen" id="scen" placeholder="Enter a scentence">-->
    <p id='scen'>Hello my friend</p>
    <br><br>
    <label for="letter">Enter the letter</label>
    <input type="text" name="letter" id="letter" placeholder="Enter a letter" min="1">
    <br>
    <button type="button" onClick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
  </form>



<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>


    <script >
    function myFunction(){
 
    var scen = document.getElementById('scen').innerHTML;
    var spa = ' ';
    var scen1 = scen.split(" ").join(spa);
    var letter = document.getElementById('letter').value;
    let err = "The letter does not exist in the sentence"
    let result = scen.indexOf(letter);
    var len = scen.length;
    var a = 3;
    var k = 0

    for(var i = 0; i < scen1.length; i++)
    {
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML += '<span id="w' + i + '">' + scen1[i] + '</span>'
    }
    
    while(k <= len){
      if(result>=0){
        document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML = scen.substring(result,result+1);
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = len;
      }
      else{
        document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML = err;
         a--;
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = a;
        break;
          }
        if(a==0){
          window.alert('game over');
          
        }
      k++;
    }
  }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it does run more than once - put a `console.log(k, len)` inside the loop and you can see that it does.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the break condition in Else part of your code is making code to exit from loop.

Please see below code and comments which I have added in your code... and let me know...

```js
function myFunction() {

  var scen = document.getElementById('scen').innerHTML;
  var spa = ' ';
  var scen1 = scen.split(" ").join(spa);
  var letter = document.getElementById('letter').value;
  let err = "The letter does not exist in the sentence"
  let result = scen.indexOf(letter);
  var len = scen.length;
  var a = 3;
  var k = 0

  for (var i = 0; i < scen1.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML += '<span id="w' + i + '">' + scen1[i] + '</span>'
  }

  while (k <= len) {
  //console.log("Loop iteration ->",k); /*you can uncomment this statement to debug the loop is working or not *?
    if (result >= 0) {
      document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML = scen.substring(result, result + 1);
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = len;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML = err;
      a--;
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = a;
     // break;  /* Commented this line so that your loop will run*/
    }
    if (a == 0) {
      window.alert('game over');

    }
    k++;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <p>Find letter:</p>

  <form id="chk" method="post">
    <label for="scen">Enter a scentence</label>
    <!--<input type="text" name="scen" id="scen" placeholder="Enter a scentence">-->
    <p id='scen'>Hello my friend</p>
    <br><br>
    <label for="letter">Enter the letter</label>
    <input type="text" name="letter" id="letter" placeholder="Enter a letter" min="1">
    <br>
    <button type="button" onClick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
  </form>



  <p id="demo"></p>
  <p id="demo2"></p>
  <p id="demo3"></p>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, your code works, thanks for the help!!